# Proguard with Parceler and Realm

Tags: android, realm, proguard, parcelable, parceler

I'm using Realm and Parceler and everything is working fine but when I enable the Proguard I'm getting an error when doing:

```
Parcels.wrap(obj)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to find generated Parcelable class for io.realm.g, verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class io.realm.g$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.
```

Although I have configured the proguard rules like:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for realm  ----------
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class * { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.*
##---------------End: proguard configuration for realm  ----------
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Parcel  ----------
-keep interface org.parceler.Parcel
-keep @org.parceler.Parcel class * { *; }
-keep class **$$Parcelable { *; }
-keep class org.parceler.Parceler$$Parcels
-keep @org.parceler.Parcel class * { *; }
-keep class *$$Parcelable { *; }
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Parcel  ----------
```

The object I'm trying to parcel looks like:

```
@Parcel(implementations = { ContentRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = { Content.class })
public class Content extends RealmObject {
    ....
}
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add this and see if it helps:

```
#realm
-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**
```

I think the issue is that while you keep the names of your RealmObjects, you don't actually keep the names of your Realm proxy classes.

So this line

```
-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
```

Should be enough on its own.

Comment: Only `-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject` is enough, as it is said.